# A holomorphic function that is expressed as a product of two formal power series

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Let $f$ be a holomorphic complex-valued function defined in a neighborhood of the origin $0\in \Bbb C$. Since holomorphic functions are analytic, we can express $f$ as a power series $\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n z^n$ with positive radius of convergence. Suppose there are two power series $g=\sum_{n\geq 0} b_nz^n$ and $h=\sum_{n\geq 0} c_nz^n$ such that $gh=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_nz^n$ in the ring $\Bbb C[[z]]$ of power series. (Thus the formal product of $g$ and $h$ is $f$.) How can we assure that $g$ and $h$ are holomorphic near $0$? This is claimed in p.69 of Miranda's book *Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces*, but i can't see why.

Comment: You need to work with the subring $\mathbb{C}\{\!\{z\}\!\}$ instead of $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$.

Comment: @user10354138 What is the definition of $\Bbb C\{\{z\}\}$?

Comment: The subring of $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$ with radius of convergence $R>0$ (so e.g., $\sum n!z^n\notin\mathbb{C}\{\!\{z\}\!\}$ but $\in\mathbb{C}[[z]]$)..